# Anaconda python shell interpreter running under SGE gives ImportError: No module named site

Tags: python, anaconda, sungridengine

I am seeing different behavior for an anaconda 2.7 python installation vs. the same python version compiled from source on our SGE cluster.

When I use the -S option to the qsub command the anaconda 2.7 python fails:

```
printf "import os\nprint os.environ" | qsub -S /home/eroller/anaconda2/bin/python

Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
ImportError: No module named site
```

The python compiled from source however, works as expected. Note that both of these python installations work on a local node so I don't expect too many other people have run into this issue. It is only through the qsub command using the -S option to set the shell interpeter to be python.

I know I can set the PYTHONHOME enviornment variable and get this to work, but I am trying to have the anaconda installation work without any modifications to the environment as the python compiled from source does.

Any ideas what could be different about how anaconda python is trying to find prefix compared to the python compiled from source. I tried modifying the RPATH to the python binary, but I have concluded the difference in behavior must be in the compiled libpython2.7.so library.

Update with some more information I have gathered:
Using the `strings` command I see the prefix path exists in the python binary from the anaconda installation, but not in the python binary compiled from source. However, looking at the strings in libpython2.7.so I see the prefix in the .so file when compiled from source, but not in the .so file from the anaconda installation. Clearly something is different in the source code for the python binary and .so library for the anaconda installation. Perhaps someone from Continuum Analytics can comment on the changes that were made?